# How to handle a n:m relation correctly with PHP&MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, nm

i've got 3 tables:

```
+-----------------+
|   validations   |
+----+-------+----+
| id | param | ...
+----+-------+
```

```
+------------------+
|   replacements   |
+----+-------------+
| id | replacement |
+----+-------------+
```

```
+--------------------------------+
|    validations-replacements    |
+---------------+----------------+
| validation_id | replacement_id |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Now I'm running my SQL query on that tables (with joins of course). And what I receive in PHP is sth. like that:

```
...
[6] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 11
    [search_param] => Dänische Belletristik
    [replacement] => Denmark
)

[7] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 11
    [search_param] => Dänische Belletristik
    [replacement] => Fiction
)
...
```

Now, in my PHP-Array I've got the same 'search_param' and 'id' multiple times. That sucks for printing it to screen. I could group the data by 'id' to avoid that, but then I've only got 1 'replacement' value available.

What I'm looking for would be an result like this:

```
...
[7] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 11
    [search_param] => Dänische Belletristik
    [replacement] => array(Denmark, Fiction)
)
...
```

What I want to know: Is that possible with my table structure by just fixing the query? Or do I have to care about that in my PHP-Code - if so: any hints how to do it best? There's plenty of data...
Is my table structure correct? I'm still a bit uncertain when it comes to databases...

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to show all replacements for a certain search param? Assuming your query is something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM validations_replacements vr 
INNER JOIN validations v ON v.id = vr.validation_id 
INNER JOIN replacements r ON r.id = vr.replacement_id
WHERE v.param = '$search_param'
```

You can either group them in PHP by playing with the result array, assuming your results object is `$results`:

```
$replacements = array() ;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $currSearchParam = $result['search_param'];
    $currReplacement = $result['replacement'] ;
    if (!isset($replacements[$currSearchParam])) {
        $replacements[$currSearchParam] = array() ;
    }
    $replacements[$currSearchParam][] = $currReplacement;
}

//I'll let you fill in the blanks like object id or naming the array keys as you wish
```

OR you can do it in mysql, then just iterate over the result in PHP:

```
SELECT v.id, v.param, GROUP_CONCAT(r.replacement)
FROM validations_replacements vr 
INNER JOIN validations v ON v.id = vr.validation_id 
INNER JOIN replacements r ON r.id = vr.replacement_id
WHERE v.param = '$search_param'
GROUP BY v.id
```

With [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you will get all a single result line for each search param, and all its replacements in a comma separated string, which you can then easily work with by iterating over the result in PHP:

```
$replacements = array() ;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $currSearchParam = $result['search_param'];
    $currReplacements = $result['replacements'] ;
    $replacements[$currSearchParam] = explode(',', $currReplacements) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact GROUP_CONCAT is new to me but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @d.hill You're quite welcome :) GROUP_CONCAT is very useful that way, saving you the extra iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)